# Create hyperlink from text in another cell in excel

Tags: excel, vba, hyperlink

I am trying to add a hyperlink (a href="url/category/***H5***")text(/a) to the beginning of cell ***B5*** referencing ***H5***. I think a VBA macro is probably the best way, but if it can be done using just formulas that works too. My VBA is not very good. :D Thanks in advance if you can help!

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: Ive tried using ="Text"&***H5***&"text", but I have run into to many problems seeing as the cell contains a lot of text and html code already. My VBA is terrible and don't know where to start

Answer (score 1):

```
' here is the code that cn create hyperlink for you question. 
'  
Dim rng As Range

Set rng = ActiveSheet.Range("B5")

rng.Parent.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=rng, Address:="", SubAddress:= _
        "H5", TextToDisplay:="this is long text"
```

Comment: +1 does what it says on the can, as apparently the OP can't be bothered to give you Answer points!